# angular 4 material finding tab index from tab header

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

i have a standard mat-tab with a difference that they are rendered dynamically based on a list of array. something like below:

```
 <mat-tab-group>
                  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tb of dynTabs">
                        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                              {{tb.label}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon (click)="removeTab($event)">close</mat-icon>
                        </ng-template>
                        <!-- tab content area -->
                        <div>      
                              my blaw blaw contents
                        </div>
                  </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
```

the .ts has following

```
     this.dynTabs.push(
          {"label": "Opportunities"},
     {"label": "Opportunities1"},
     {"label": "Opportunities2"}
        );

removeTab(ev){
    console.log(ev)
  }
```

my questions is as i might hit the close icon even if the tab is not selected so how do i find the index of the tab whose close icon is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `tb` into the `(click)` handler in the following way:

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tb of dynTabs">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         {{tb.label}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon (click)="removeTab(tb)">close</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <!-- tab content area -->
    <div>      
        my blaw blaw contents
    </div>
</mat-tab>
```

You can also pass index in the following way:

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tb of dynTabs; let i=index">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         {{tb.label}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon (click)="removeTab(i)">close</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <!-- tab content area -->
    <div>      
        my blaw blaw contents
    </div>
</mat-tab>
```

You can still pass `$event` in both cases in the following way:

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tb of dynTabs">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         {{tb.label}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon (click)="removeTab(tb, $event)">close</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <!-- tab content area -->
    <div>      
        my blaw blaw contents
    </div>
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: what is tab here that is passed in removeTab ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be `tb` from `ngFor`. Edited my post.

Comment: hmm as tb does not have any index stores so i guess i need to use the index based solution. what is index in let i = index ?

Comment: `index` is the variable that Angular introduces for you to assign in *ngFor initialization. There are many of them actually. Here is the good article regarding ngFor: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/